# Why do R/Shiny inputs in datatable not work correctly after updating datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to create a datatable with Shiny input elements (checkboxInput or textInput). This works well until I update the datatable. If I add more rows with more input elements, only the new elements work. I thought the table would be recreated every time I update it and the ids would be associated with the new input elements. The code example below illustrates the problem. It creates a table with one row first. If I then create a table with two rows using the dropdown on the left, I can only read the values of the second row in the output table. Any change to the inputs of the first row has no impact on the ouput table.

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  updateTable <- reactive({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)
    df <- data.frame(check = unlist(lapply(1:num, function(i) as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("check_", i), label = paste0("check", i), value = 0)))),
               text = unlist(lapply(1:num, function(i) as.character(textInput(paste0("text_",i), label = paste0("text", i), value = "")))))
  })

  output$input_ui <- DT::renderDataTable(
    updateTable(),
    server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
    options = list(
      dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,lengthChange = TRUE,
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
    )
  )

  output$table <- renderTable({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)
    data.frame(lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      paste(input[[paste0("check_", i)]], input[[paste0("text_",i)]], sep = " : ")
    }))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("num", "select number of inputs", choices = seq(1,10,1))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("input_ui"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is provided here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/ZUMBGGl1sss/7sdRQecLBAAJ

As far as I understand, it allows to "force" a complete unbind of all checkbox/textinpts before redrawing the table thanks to the use of:

```
session$sendCustomMessage('unbind-DT', 'input_ui')
```

. I do not pretend to really understsand it, but apparently it works. See below for a possible implementation.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  updateTable <- reactive({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)
    session$sendCustomMessage('unbind-DT', 'input_ui')
    df <- data.frame(
      check = unlist(lapply(1:num, function(i) as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("check_", i), label = paste0("check", i), value = 0)))),
      text = unlist(lapply(1:num, function(i) as.character(textInput(paste0("text_",i), label = paste0("text", i), value = "")))))
    tbl <- DT::datatable(df, escape = FALSE,
                         selection = "none", 
                         options = list(
                           dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,lengthChange = TRUE,
                           preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                           drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                         ))

  })

  output$input_ui <- DT::renderDataTable(
    updateTable(),
    server = FALSE
  )

  output$table <- renderTable({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)
    data.frame(lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      paste(input[[paste0("check_", i)]], input[[paste0("text_",i)]], sep = " : ")
    }))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("num", "select number of inputs", choices = seq(1,10,1))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("input_ui"),
      tags$script(HTML(
        "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbind-DT', function(id) {
          Shiny.unbindAll($('#'+id).find('table').DataTable().table().node());
        })")),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your response. It helped me a lot to understand the problem.

Comment: I implemented this solution now and it works perfectly. Thanks again. One more thing: In my app (unlike the example above) the table can be empty (NULL). In this case, I had to make sure not to call session$sendCustomMessage. Otherwise the app gets stuck without error (Console or JavaScript).